# PhantomJS onResourceReceived no stream

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, network-monitoring

I am trying to receive the URL of a mpeg live stream.
Because the url of streams might change, but a site rarely does, I am using onResourceReceived to listen for the url of the stream.

So far, I have not been getting anything (not even errors).
Here is my code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
address;

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: netlog.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
address = system.args[1];

page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
    console.log('requested: ' + JSON.stringify(req, undefined, 4));
};

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    system.stdout.writeLine('console: ' + msg);
};

page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
    console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(res, undefined, 4));
};

page.open(address, function (status) {
if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('FAIL to load the address');
}

var radio = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.getElementById('button_playpause');
});
console.log('Radio variable: ');
console.log(radio);
console.log('Clicking button: ');
$(radio).click();

phantom.exit();
});
}
```

I adapted the code found here: http://phantomjs.org/network-monitoring.html
The website I am trying this code on is the following: http://radioplayer.npo.nl/mini-player/radio4/

Why does the url not show up when PhantomJS clicks the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomJS (versions 1 and 2) doesn't support `<audio>`, `<video>` or flash. You won't see the requests that you expect, because they are not sent.

SlimerJS which has the same API as PhantomJS uses the Gecko engine and supports `<audio>` and `<video>`.

Comment: Thats a shame. Do you know any alternative that does support audio?

Comment: I don't know any headless browser that does, but SlimerJS has the same API as PhantomJS and uses the Gecko engine

Comment: As long as there is no flash involved, SlimerJS works by using the same exact script! Thanks