# PhantomJS network monitoring get result after page loaded

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, network-monitoring

I have a page with video player that put comment in network monitor during video playing.
I want to get all information after page loaded, but ["netsniff.js"](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/netsniff.js) return me just network until page loaded, I'm looking to a way to continue to get network also after page loaded

Any help ? Thanks

Comment: Video player? You won't get it, because PhantomJS doesn't support it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhantomJS onResourceReceived no stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742292/phantomjs-onresourcereceived-no-stream)

Comment: the video player send data to network monitor, I just want to get those data, I'm looking on player by selenium.... There is a way to get monitor data after page loaded ?

Comment: Not with PhantomJS except when the video player is in pure JavaScript (flash and `<video>` are not supported).

Comment: do you know if there is a way to get network monitor "on demand" ? I mean my page finished to load, waiting 5 minutes and then get the network monitor ?

Comment: You can hold off `createHAR()` and `phantom.exit()` after page load with `setTimeout`.

Comment: I tried that but return me just the event that append when page loaded, not the next events...

Comment: Then nothing else happened afterwards. That's why I linked the other Q&A. No video is even loaded so you won't see any action on it.